Problem getting MikTeX to recognize OSX fonts
I have a clean MiKTeX installation on OSX and have a few new fonts installed. I want to start using these fonts in Xelatex but the installation does not see them. The error message I get is:
Couldn't open `Baskerville Ten P.cfg'

hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)


Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  /Users/dima/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/miktex/log/miktex-maketfm.log
Error producing PDF.
! Package fontspec Error: 
(fontspec)                The font "Baskerville Ten Pro" cannot be found;
(fontspec)                this may be but usually is not a fontspec bug.
(fontspec)                Either there is a typo in the font name/file, the
(fontspec)                font is not installed (correctly), or there is a
(fontspec)                bug in the underlying font loading engine
(fontspec)                (XeTeX/luaotfload).

Looking inside miktex-maketfm.log I see the line

FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font "Baskerville Ten
Pro".

I have already executed both Refresh file name database and Refresh font map files in MiKTeX Console, it didn't help.

I wouldn't use miktex on macOS. Most mac users will use either mactex or directly texlive, which is thus much better tested.

(also xelatex is known to be picky with fonts - I would use lualatex if you can)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I checked luatex and everything compiles just fine with it

then the name you used is either wrong or xelatex can not find the font through fontconfig.

@UlrikeFischer the name is correct because the document compiles with Xelatex on Windows. this seems to be an OSX problem

on osx/linux system xelatex uses the system fontconfig, on windows (which doesn't have fontconfig) a fontconfig provided by the tex systems.  So check if the font is found by other applications.
